Linux disk space running full
Trying to understand more of Linux and why our diskspace keeps running full with what. Little to none experience with Linux so bear with me
/dev/sda2 is mounted on / and this disk keeps running full

If I check a level deeper I can see

Now there is this 18GB on /
How can I see what is actually taking up this space? Folders like /etc /home /var I can check the content but I fail to see what files are directly on the /
All normal folder that would run full like cache or logs or /tmp are checked and emptied and still the disk is at 96% which I think is not normal.
Any other tips are welcome as well ofcourse.
Thanks in advance.
EDIT
Command ls -lst /  gives the following result

I'm not sure what to make of this but does this mean this 'swap' thing takes up the majority of the space? Or can this be ignored.

Hard to know for sure; but /swap is probably a file-based swap for your computer's memory. (you can run swapon to see). If it is your computer's swap space; that is a static file which will not change in size; it's size is probably a multiple of your RAM (1x, 1.5x or 2x).

There is a note half off the top of the du run indicating it could not read some things.  This means you probably where not running as root, so there could be 10G of data your user just isn't allowed to see.

It's preferable to post plain text rather than screenshots, for the benefit of people using screen readers.

It would have been helpful if you had provided the actual commands which gave these results (appears to be df & du).
It looks as if there is 18G used in /.
That's bad.
You should NEVER add files there. Not only does it create issues with managing the storage, it also implies that you are running data processing tasks or logging a root. Also bad.

How can I see what is actually taking up this space?

ls -lst / would be a good starting point.
You won't see files which have been deleted (but are still open). lsof | grep 'deleted' might help if you don't see what you expect from ls

Thank you, I've ran the first command you gave and added the output to the post. Can you help me interpret the results? Because on sight I never seem to add up to the correct 18GB in use..

The swap file is around 4Gb, not 18Gb. That's sort of OK where it is. You are still missing 14Gb. The total figure at the top tells me you've not omitted any significant files (don't post pictures of text you can copy copy paste as text). So you're not seeing what you EXPECT to see.

You must remember that the 18G in / include all the subdirectories.  The 4G swap plus the rest easily adds to 18G.

....but there's 28G used in the volume.

True, and I think between answers and comments we have four possible explanations -- so far.  (and I know a fifth, but it seems unlikely.)

Turned out for this case it where indeed deleted files that took up a lot of space. More specifically lots of logfiles from docker.

Why is used space on / bad? Most of OS files are there, surely you can't expect Linux to occupy nothing?

Do not forget that du can't inspect dirs protected from reading. Use sudo.

"Most of OS files are there," - no, they are in subdirectories - since I couldn't see the command the OP ran it wasn't clear that the 18G included the subdirectories also listed by the same operation. And du reports errors when it encounters directories it cannot read from from which are not shown in OPs screenshots.

Note the OP doesn't have a separate partition for /home, so home contents will fill up /

Use something like ncdu to visualize your disk space usage. There’s other similar tools as well, but this one runs w/out UI, and runs great!
https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu

Worth mentioning that deleted files will linger until they're closed by the process having them open.

Good point, indeed!

very good point indeed, deleted docker logfiles where the culprit on this case

Step 1, see what du can find in the active filesystem:
du -xm / | sort -n | tail -40

Run du on the problem filesystem (/),
Use -x to limit the exam to that filesystem
Use -m to make sorting simpler (I find it a bit more readable than using -h on both)

If it finds something big, you can examine and remove it.   If it doesn't find  the corresponding 28G of data, you likely have one of 2 things happening:

Open files deleted.   While a log file or other is open, deleting removes it from the directory (no longer visible to du), but not from the filesystem.   You might check for those with sudo lsof -nP +L1.  (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68523/find-and-remove-large-files-that-are-open-but-have-been-deleted).    If this is a single-user machine and it's not too onerous, you could consider just rebooting to disconnect all open filehandles and allow the filesystem to free the space.

Mount point hiding.   If there is data under (as an example) the var or tmp directories, that data will be hidden from access when the /var and /tmp filesystems are mounted on top.   You can unmount and examine them one by one, or take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/access-to-original-contents-of-mount-point.   Using that technique you can remount a copy of /, then run du on that copy and examine underneath the mount points.



Whenever this happens to me, I do a manual recursion something like:
du -hs /* > /du.out

Then when it is apparent that the bloat is from (let's say:) /var, I repeat the process:
du -hs /var/* > /var/du.out

Rinse and repeat until you drill down to your problem location.
The above could obviously be improved as some sort of script; but generally speaking, if the drive has filled up; then you only have the small space reserved for root and many programs won't run if they need scratch space on disk.

If you're doing to do that, just use -d1 (or -hd1) against the directory. No need to shell glob.

@Bob is correct, but I will go one step further.  The shell glob will actually MISS files and directories, notably any that begin with a period (.).  The only good thing to say about it is that it will do the top-level files individually (but for that just add the -a option).  Personally, I often just do du some/directory | sort -n.   Or sometimes I use the KDE tool filelight.

Sometime, it`s some files was deleted, but the process still open the file, run this command maybe find out the process
lsof | grep deleted

And then kill it
kill -9 $pid

This is detailed verification steps
## check disk size
$ du -sh /data 2>/dev/null
956M    /data

$ df -h /data
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb         50G 1008M   46G   3% /data

## create a 2GB file
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/data/myfile.iso bs=1024k count=2000
2000+0 records in
2000+0 records out
2097152000 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 1.49613 s, 1.4 GB/s

## check disk size again
$ du -sh /data 2>/dev/null
2.9G    /data

$ df -h /data
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb         50G  3.0G   44G   7% /data

## create and run demo script
$ cat test.py 
import time
f = open('/data/myfile.iso','r')
time.sleep(1200)

$ nohup python test.py &
[1] 1522
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’

## Delete file, and then check disk size
$ rm -f myfile.iso

## now disk size is different, "du" print "956M" and "df" print "3.0G"
$ du -sh /data 2>/dev/null
956M    /data

$ df -h /data
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb         50G  3.0G   44G   7% /data

## find the deleted file and kill process pid
$ lsof |grep delete
python     1522          root    3r      REG               8,16 2097152000         12 /data/myfile.iso (deleted)

$ kill 1522
[1]+  Terminated              nohup python test.py

## This is end of disk size, du and df is eq
$ du -sh /data 2>/dev/null
956M    /data

$ df -h /data
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb         50G 1008M   46G   3% /data


It is rare that you should start with kill -9.  Start with just kill, and let the program clean up after itself if it needs to.  Also be aware that even kill -9 doesn't always work.

You might also find kill -KILL easier to read and remember.  (All the signals have symbolic names: TERM, HUP, QUIT, ABRT, INT, KILL.  I'd suggest trying them in that order, with KILL as the last resort.)

I think the most obvious issue for why we can only see 18GB used in du of 28GB used in df is in the du image.
If you look carefully at the top, you will see the bottom half of the start of something like:
du: cannot read directory '/some/directory': Permission denied

In short, du could not read all the disk.  Please redo the du as root, possibly with any other security changes needed to let it see everything.
If this doesn't account for everything, please post what you get.  But do so as text, not as an image, and include the starting command and any errors that came out.

You appear to have lost 10G.  You might try forcing a fsck on the disk.  Many modern distributions disable it completely on journaled filesystems, but I personally have seen too much corruption even with the journal to permit it to be disabled.
You either need:

a distribution specific means to force the fsck, typically as part of a reboot.
to switch to single user mode, preferably before / is mounted read/write, and do the fsck there.
to boot from other media and fsck /dev/sda2 yourself.

If there are many issues, I would recommend use tune2fs to change the fsck requirements for the disk.

Lost to OS! If he runs du under sudo he will quickly find the lost space.

@Basilevs  Wrong answer.  This answer is about corrupt filesystem.  My other answer is about needing root.  Depending on a security module, you might need more than just root (but I don't use Linux security modules, so I can't say what).

/var is taking 8.7G. Check out /var/logs. You can use such tools as baobab to quickly grasp what is taking too much space.
My guess is that systemd writes logs too often. Try the following:
sudo journalctl --rotate
sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=1s

If the space frees up, set SystemMaxUse=100M in /etc/systemd/journald.conf.

DON'T clean /var/log before finding out what is there.  There might be something repeating a LOT that needs examination.  simply paging through the log files should help to notice a pattern.
